# CorePlot graph misplaced in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

In `CorePlot` I have a graph that looks like this in `iOS5`:
[image]

and like this in `iOS6`:
[image]

As you can see it is getting misplaced a lot.
The code I use for positioning it stays the same:

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop    = 20.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight  = 0.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 0.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft   = 0.0;

[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:plot01, plot02, nil]];

CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
[xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.4f)];
plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
[yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.6f)];
plotSpace.yRange = yRange;

x.gridLinesRange = yRange;
y.gridLinesRange = xRange;
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? I'm really stuck here, tried chaining the values here and there but the result stays the same.

I'm using the latest version of Core Plot which is `1.1` and `Xcode 4.6`

Comment: how it is misplaced? graph is plotted correctly as the values.Are you saying the complete view is dragged or something else?

Comment: @LithuT.V Nope, the view frame **does not** change in any way, it stays the same! That's what confusing me the most

Comment: Big change in iOS 6 is *autolayout*. Check if it's enabled and disable it if necassary (quick search on google will help you).

Comment: @rdurand Nice guess, but nope, I'm not using IB or Storyboards so this doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 did you bother reading previous comments? I am **not** using it, sir.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 read the 2nd comment.

Comment: nslog frame in both, ios5 and 6

Comment: @Rajneesh071 I have **already** done this, thanks. Any more interesting ideas, huh?

Comment: Could provide your test environment? iPhone 4(s) or 5, iPad (Retina or non Retina) and are you using a device or the simulator? Biggest change I can think of is the iPhone 5 has a 4in screen and only supports iOS 6 and >.

Comment: @Joe Real device with iOS6 and a simulator with iOS5. It runs just fine in iOS6 both on Retina 3.5 and Retina 4 inch displays

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/coreplot-discuss/lVQ-isqu930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known issue with Core Plot 1.1. It's fixed in the latest code, but there hasn't been another full release since then. You can pull the latest code from [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) with Mercurial to get the fix.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! I was close to figuring it out myself :)